# For Loop keeps returning same value

Tags: php

Am using a For loop to return all rows from table. It goes through each row properly but keeps returning the same value even though it has gone on to the next row.

Code Below:

```
function setLayer($result_set, $row){

    $str  = "MyMap_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $i, 0),"UTF-8","SJIS")."_".mb_convert_encoding(mssql_result($result_set, $i, 1),"UTF-8","SJIS");
    return "".$str." = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( \"".$str."\",\"http://192.168.0.69/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/mapserver/data/toyama/toyama_mymap.map&service=WMS&SRS=EPSG:2449&VERSION=1.1.1&format=image/PNG&layers=".$str."\", {'layers': '".$str."'},  {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: false,opacity:0.5,alpha:true});
    map.addLayer(".$str.");\n\n";
}
```

Loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<=$group_layer_row; $i++){
    echo setLayer($rs_group_layer, $i);
}
```

My reasoning is that though the loop goes through all the rows, $str does not change to reflect another row so it keeps giving the same value though it the row value is different.... close?

Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function accepts `$row` but in the body you use `$i`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late reply, server's went down so couldn't implement this change till now. The loop is returning the proper value per row now. Did get another error but that is a different question for sql so will be making a new question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add return at the end of the function. 
Please consider @Sylverdrag suggestion also.

Comment: There is a return. The problem is that he is passing a $row variable, but tries to use a $i variable which doesn't exist.